# Passing string value from activity class to a non activity class

Tags: java, android, string, android-activity

i'm new in android and i'm trying to pass a string from a TextView from the MainActivity to the Client.java class without activity.
I'm actually trying to make it doing in MainActivity :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Client.class);
    i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", String.valueOf(indr));
```

While in Client :

```
Context context;
Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
static Bundle getIp = getIntent.getExtra("STRING_I_NEED");
public static final Bundle SERVERIP = getIp;
```

But that's saying "

> Cannot resolve symbol "getIntent" in the string
>     static Bundle getIp = getIntent.getExtra("STRING_I_NEED");

Client code:

```
public class Client {
private static String mIP= "";
private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = mIP;
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;


public void setIp(String _IP) {
    mIP = _IP;
}
public Client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}


public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(SERVERIP));

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {

            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}


public interface OnMessageReceived {
    void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

And here is the MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Server server;
Client client;
public static String message,ippi;
public static TextView terminale,indr,msg;
TextView log;
DataBaseHandler myDB;
allert Allert;
SharedPreferences prefs;
String s1 = "GAB Tamagnini SRL © 2017 \n" +
            "Via Beniamino Disraeli, 17,\n" +
            "42124 Reggio Emilia \n" +
            "Telefono: 0522 / 38 32 22 \n" +
            "Fax: 0522 / 38 32 72 \n" +
            "Partita IVA, Codice Fiscale \n" +
            "Reg. Impr. di RE 00168780351 \n" +
            "Cap. soc. € 50.000,00 i.v. \n" +  "" +
            "REA n. RE-107440 \n" +
            "presso C.C.I.A.A. di Reggio Emilia";
ImageButton settings,helps,allerts,home;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    server = new Server(this);
    myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(this);
    new connectTask().execute("");

    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_avviso);
    settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.impo);
    helps = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aiut);
    allerts = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.msge);
    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gab);
    terminale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminal);
    indr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.indr);

    Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchData();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            indr.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            terminale.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    client.setIp(indr.getText().toString());


    cursor.close();
    server.Parti();



    message = indr.getText().toString();

    if (client != null) {
        client.sendMessage(message);
    }

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Client.SERVERIP, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent impostazioni = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), settingsLogin.class);
            startActivity(impostazioni);
        }
    });

    helps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent pgHelp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), help.class);
            startActivity(pgHelp);
        }
    });

    allerts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Server.count = 0;
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
            msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent pgAlert = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), allert.class);
            startActivity(pgAlert);
        }
    });

}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Client> {

    @Override
    protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        client = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        client.run();

        return null;
    }

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    server.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: why dont use a method for that?

Comment: What is `Client.java` ??

Comment: Try this 
Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
static Bundle getIp = intent.getExtra("STRING_I_NEED");

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's a TCP Client class.

Comment: @hareeshJ if i do that getExtra is saying "cannot resolve method "getExtra(java.lang.String)"

Comment: @Ivan any example for method?

Comment: @I.Mytyuk Answered with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Since `Client.java` (according to you) is not an Activity type class, you cannot call/invoke `Client.java` using an `Intent`. `Intent` is only used for invoking: `Activities`, `BroadcastReceiver`, and `Services`.

Your Client.java does not extend an Activity, Broadcast, or a Service. This is the reason why you don't have the `getIntent()` function, or even the functions `onCreate()`, `onReceive(),`onStartCommand()`or`onHandleIntent()'` for that matter.

---

**Correct way:**

**1.** So what you have to do is create an object of that class just like any other object and call its setter. You can define a public method in you class to set the value of IP:

```
YourClass {
   private String mIP;

   public void setIp(String _IP) {
       mIp = _IP;
    }
}
```

And in the MainActivity class you can just call that method after the object is initialized:

```
MyClassObject.setIp("127.0.0.1");
```

**2.** Define an overloaded constructor, and set the value using it.

**3.** Create a `public static String IP` in `MainActivity`, assign value to it and then in your class do this to retrieve the value:

```
YourClass {
       private String mIP;

       public void getIp() {
           mIP = MainActivity.IP;
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually i did this in Main : client.setIp(indr.getText().toString()); because i have to set in mIP a text from a TextView and not doing in manually but still when i'm trying to visualize it it results null

Comment: Kindly edit your question and post that relevant code so I can see where the problem is, any way is it that you are trying to get value from an EditText via user input (that is different from TextView)??

Comment: Actually i'm setting text in a EditText in settings.java class but i pass that value in data base and retrive it in MainActivity after i set this text in a TextView and i'm trying to pass this text in a string to Client.java non activity class, ill post now MainActivity and Client code wait a while.

Comment: I think the client is not intialized at the point you call this client.setIp(indr.getText().toString()); since you are doing it in a Async Task which is a separate thread

Comment: There is no errors, just when i'm trying now to check if there is anyvalue in SERVERIP the Toast with which i check it results empty when there have to be a text got from a TextView in MainActivity.

Comment: Hmm...anyway then you can always use a shared pref, ill explain it in another answer

Comment: Actually i have stored that data in my SQlite database maybe i can retrive this data and set it using it instead the SharedPrefs?

Comment: Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchData();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            indr.setText(cursor.getString(1));client.setIP(cursor.getString(1));
            terminale.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

Comment: Yea just do this ^^

Comment: Only if you are sure the client is initialized before you call setIp() in it

Comment: Actually fetching data from DB when i try to visualize data from SERVERIP in a Toast that says "TextView" ...

Comment: Great now that's work i was putting a empty mIP in SERVERIP so i had to initialize it in the setIp function, thank you your tips were very helpful.

Comment: When ill have 15 rep ill do upwote :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149381/discussion-between-i-mytyuk-and-rahim-shahid).

Answer (score 1):

In your Client class.

```
public void setString(String yourString){
    variableToStoreStringInClass = yourString;
}
```

And in your MainActivity, where you want to send the string to the Client.

```
Client yourClient = new Client();
yourClient.setString("Enter the string");
```

---

Or you can use an static method:

In Client class:

```
public static void setString(String yourString){
    variableToStoreStringInClass = yourString;
}
```

And in your MainActivity

```
Client.setString("Enter the string");
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this but how can i set in Client.setString() a text that is in a TextView? i'm trying doing client.setIp(indr.getText().toString()); but when i'm visualizzing it in a Toast that result null

Comment: where are you showing the Toast? Where do you do the `indr.getText.toString` ?

Comment: i'm showing Toast in MainActivity on click, while doing indr.getText.ToString in OnCreate.

Comment: But actually i don't need that Toast i made it just for test if i've passed that string.

Comment: in the Oncreate you still have no text in the TextView i think, so when you are assigning the ip you are assigning an empty string, and passing it to your Client class. Try to do the setIp inside the onClick

Comment: Same, Toast risults empty also if i do it onClick.

Comment: try taking out the `final` of the SERVERIP

Comment: Still empty, and i actually need to do it onCreate so the TCP Client will send the ip every time it's run.

Comment: if you print the indr.getText().toString() in the log, does it have value? or empty too? Try passing and url hardcoded as client.setIp ("127.0.0.1") and see if works

Comment: Probably there is something wrong while assigning the mIP because also if i hardcode with client.setIp("127.0.0.1") and assign it in Client.class as String SERVERIP = mIP that return empty field in toast.

Comment: other thing is in your setIp you assing mIp but not SERVERIP, or is this your last comment?

Comment: Also if i put SERVERIP instead of mIp that's still result empty

Comment: are you sure your asynctask finished?

Comment: I think so but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In your Settings activity when you set the String in that TextView also save it in a shared preference like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

prefs.edit().putString("IP", IP_String).apply();
```

And then in main activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String ip = prefs.getString("IP", "AnyDefaultValue");

client.setIp(ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intialize static string in MainActivity and assign textView text to that string.

In Client.java call like this MainActivity.IntializedString

Comment: if i'm trying to pass it like this when i'm trying to check if data has been passed with a toast the toast says that it's null.

Answer (score 0):

Try following sample

```
public class Client {
    Context context;
    Intent intent;
    String value = "";

    public Client(Activity activity) {
        context = activity;
        intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
        value = intent.getStringExtra("String_i_need");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i set another String in Client.java as SERVERIP = value; but when i'm trying to visualize it in a Toast in MainActivity that's result empty